# Visual Studio 2022 Startup project could not launch

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

I have this error after updating Visual Studio 2022 to 17.2.0 version.

The error message pops up when I want to close the Visual Studio by X button [image]or when I want to Build my solution  with a few projects [image](but when I build a solution with only one project the process succeeded without any error messages).

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: try to restart , your computer, if it's a recent issue that you face , may be some visual studion background task bugging, :)

Comment: Try running VS elevated, right-click the shortcut and select "Run as administrator".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the root directory of your project you will find a folder called `.vs`. (It is a hidden folder). Inside that you will find a folder with the name of your solution. Delete it and you should be good to go.

Comment: This worked for me! Spent two hours searching for a fix and this was the only thing that worked. Seems to be a VS2022 issue?

Answer (score 0):

All was solved by deleting `CurrentSettings.vssettings`. It is usually located at Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Settings If not, go to `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Import and Export Settings` ' to find the location of this file.

Comment: Thanks for answering to my question, but I'm afraid even after following the steps you mentioned I still have the same problem.