# Closing Visual Studio Community 2022 - Cryptic 0x80030050 error

Tags: visual-studio

I have two main solutions/projects I'm working on.

In the first, everything closes fine.

In the second, every time I close the project, I get:

[image]

This prevents VS from closing and I have to end the VS task. Further, this doesn't let me save my workspace - opened/pinned files, etc.

I've checked my event logs, visual studio logs, etc. - nothing.

Any idea where this may be coming from or how to find it?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: SOLVED! Please see this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72218650/visual-studio-2022-startup-project-could-not-launch